# What is quads in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am in the middle of developing an android game and from [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html), I see

```
Draws batched quads using indices.
```

But I am not sure what the **SpriteBatch** class really is for. Can anyone tell me about the **quads** mentioned there.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know libgdx specifically but to me a quad is a plane defined by 4 vertices. I assume they have to be in the same 2D plane, otherwise you could divide it in more shapes. Normally a 3D shape exists out of tris and quads.

Comment: @miva2 Thank you will take in mind and do some research.

Comment: Quad is short for quadrilateral. SpriteBatch is designed for drawing sprites, which are rectangles with part of a texture mapped onto them.  In OpenGL, a rectangle or any other quadrilateral is composed of two triangles that share a common edge. The purpose of SpriteBatch is to combine (batch) many sprites into one set of data to pass to the GPU to minimize time spent transferring data.

Comment: @Tenfour04 that's a great answer!  You can use the answer box!  :)